# Device not shown on ADB even after pairing for wireless debugging on Linux

Tags: adb, linux, android-11, wireless-debugging

Wireless debugging seems to pair, but then the device just does not show up. I tried it on Mac and it works, but it does not work on Linux. I am on a Samsung phone.

I run `adb pair [IP]:[PORT] [CODE]`. It executes successfully and tells me that I am paired with the device. Then I run `adb devices` and it is just blank.

On my phone, it doesn't say that it is paired to myuser@hostname, but rather root@hostname for some reason. I even tried logging in as root and listing the devices but it is of no avail.

The above steps work fine and list the device on a Mac. The phone also shows "Connected" next to the hostname and user, and the user is not root but rather the username.

I have tried-:

1. Disabling firewall
2. Trying the tools from the official repository, AUR package, google website, etc.
3. Restarting my PC and Android phone

Comment: Yes you still need to do `adb connect` after pairing. Pairing replaces the old RSA key authentication, but making connection with the paired device is still up to the user. Though making it  a part of pairing isn't a bad idea.

Comment: This works on macOS, so this not working on Linux seems like a bug.

Answer (score 16):

As per [the official documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20220122170651/https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) (snapshot of 22 January 2022), after pairing the device, the user still needs to manually connect the device

> 9. (For Linux or Microsoft Windows only) Run `adb connect ipaddr:port`. Use the IP address and port under Wireless debugging.

Despite it is not mentioned on [the current documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#wireless-android11-command-line) anymore, **this step is still necessary** (tested on Windows).

Comment: Relevant ADB issue tracker report: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/225320059

Comment: This worked for me. Just had to `connect` after completing the `pair`.

Comment: I could make it work only by not specifying the port (`adb connect ipaddr`). Otherwise a `Connection refused` error is returned.

Comment: I had to use the same `ipaddr:port` from the debugging screen, not the same as I used `adb pair` that is the popup when you go "pair with a code" on Android